# Trying to find the last character in a non-standard length string

Tags: postgresql, substring

I'm a relatively new coder and I've been struggling with the following problem for a few days. I am trying to separate the characters after the last period in an email address so I can group results by them. To do this for the text after the @ symbol, I wrote the following code:

```
select lower(substring(email, position('@' in email))) as email
```

This code returns things like @gmail.com or @yahoo.com, which I can then group by in my longer query. However, I would also like to compare the .com results to the .net results. When I type a similar query:

```
select lower(substring(email, position('.' in email))) as email
```

it returns the first period in the email address. So my email would be returned as .lastname@gmail.com rather than .com. I've experimented with right( and left(, but these don't work with substring in Postgresql. Does anyone have any other suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. The trick was using `reverse` to find where that last period was.

**[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/03696/15)**

```
select 
  substring(email, char_length(email) - position('.' in (reverse(email))) + 1) as Domain
from yourTable
```

Comment: Question about this code. Does the char_length indicate a standard character length, or just the total char_length, which can vary across rows? 

Thanks, just trying to make sure I'm understanding and not letting stack answer all of my questions.

Comment: @CharlieTango char_length(email) returns the length of the email address. It will vary from row to row.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
select regexp_matches(email, '[^.]+$', 'g') 
from your_table
```

Comment: Thanks, can you give me more information about what the $ or g does? That was one of the problems I was having with regexp, was that I wasn't clear from the documentation what those symbols were doing.

Comment: Postgres uses standart POSIX regexp. You can find full description for it in the internet ([`wiki for example`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)). The symbol `$` means the end of the string (the mach must be made at the end of the string). The `'g'` means "greedy" (the mach must be as long as possible).

Comment: That regex wouldn't work for me but this one does `select regexp_matches('hello', '(.)$', 'g');`